# Can I use [formControl] without also needing [formGroup]?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I am using a  dropdown in my UI, but when I come to use `[formControl]` I am getting the error thrown:

> Cannot find control with unspecified name attribute

I am using ReactiveFormsModule in my `app.module.ts`.

I have Google'd and found that a solution is to use [formGroup] in the parent `div`, but I'm unsure of how to implement properly as I am defining my `formControl` from within a `subscribe`.

**myComp.component.html**

```
<div class="exceptional-status">
  <select #exceptionalSelect id="excep-status-dropdown" [formControl]="select">
    <option disabled value="default">--Exceptional statuses--</option>
    <!-- other options here with *ngFor -->
  </select>
</div>
```

**myComp.component.ts**

```
select: FormControl;

mySubscription() {
  this.myService.myFunct.subscribe(res => {
    this.select = new FormControl(res.status)
  });
}
```

Comment: your variable declaration also wrong pls check angular doc: https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, you can use `FormControlDirective` without FormGroup.

Angular expects FormControl to be defined:

```
select = new FormControl();

mySubscription() {
  this.myService.myFunct.subscribe(res => {
    this.select.setValue(res.status)
  });
}
```

Comment: Ah great! I thought it may be something similar, but wasn't sure how to go about it. I just had a Google of the difference between `setValue()` and `patchValue()` and opted for `patch` for now.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use it without FormGroup.

```
select = new FormControl();
```

For set the value:-

```
select.setValue('your data here');
```

To get the value:-

```
select.value
```

Answer (score 0):

Why would you define the form control within the subscribe? My advice would be to structure the form skeleton outside the subscription and just populate the control using

```
mySubscription() {
  this.myService.myFunct.subscribe(res => {
    this.controls['select'].patchValue(res.status);
  });
}
```

Comment: where does the `controls` come into things?